# Can't pickle thread.lock objects

Tags: python, многопоточность, python-2.7, activemq

Доброго времени суток!

При попытке портирования моего кода с linux (arch) на windows (7) возникли проблемы с созданием дочерних процессов (multiprocessing.Process).

```
from stompy import stomp
from multiprocessing import Process
import json

def tmp(q, w, e):
    print q, w, e
    return

s = stomp.Stomp(amq_ip, amq_port)
s.connect(username=amq_user, password=amq_pass)
s.subscribe({'destination':'/queue/%s' % amq_queue, 'ack':'client'})

while True:
    try:
        frame = s.receive_frame()
    except:
        continue

    # тут костылирую
    # жду советов от гуру, как избавиться
    body = json.loads(frame.as_string().split('\n\n')[1][:-1])

    p = Process(target=tmp, args=(frame, s, body))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Подписываюсь на очередь ActiveMQ, а после получения от нее нового сообщения, обработаю его в новом потоке. Под линью все отлично работает, под виндой - получаю стектрейс TypeError: can't pickle thread.lock objects.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tmp.py", line 31, in <module>
    p.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 277, in __init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 199, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 554, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 692, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 731, in save_inst
    save(stuff)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: can't pickle thread.lock objects
```

При этом, если в параметры функции нового потока не передавать дескриптор очереди (s) и фрейм (frame), то все работает нормально.
Windows 7 x64. Python 2.7.12.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае проблема в библиотеке Stompy. Вот короткий пример, иллюстрирующий проблему:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from Queue import Queue

def tmp(q, w, e):
    print q, w, e

if __name__ == "__main__":
        q = Queue()
        p = Process(target=tmp, args=("fname", q, "body"))
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

В процессе выполнения будет выброшено исключение `TypeError: can't pickle thread.lock objects`. Для того, чтобы передавать данные из одного *процесса* в другой используется модуль `pickle` - все данные им сериализируются и направляются в сериализованном виде. У Stompy в потрохах где-то создаются очереди и передать такой объект не выйдет. Исправленный пример будет выглядеть так:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
q = Manager().Queue()
```

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что данное решение предполагает отказ от использования Stompy?

Comment: Не обязательно, суть других решений сводится к тому, что не нужно передавать этот объект другим процессам.